# Time out on simple single or default shouldn't be happening

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devexpress

I am modifying an appointment of a devexpress sechudler winforms and I getting an issue with my context

```
public Appointment getApppointmentById(int AppointmentId)
    {
        Appointment q;
        try
        {

            if (AppointmentId == -1)// if the patient id is -1 we want to create a new record.
            {
                Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
                return appointment;

            }
            q=  _sourceEntities.Appointments
                .Where(w => w.ID == AppointmentId).SingleOrDefault();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("   etApppointmentById(int AppointmentId) failed.", ex);
        }
        return q;
 }
```

I am calling this method using my custominfo method

```
 private void dxsourceNetAppointments_AppointmentViewInfoCustomizing(object sender, AppointmentViewInfoCustomizingEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e != null)
        {
            if (e.ViewInfo.Appointment.Id != null)
            {

                _newAppointment = SourceDal.getApppointmentById((int)e.ViewInfo.Appointment.Id);
                _newAppointmentType = SourceDal.getAppointmentTypesById(_newAppointment.AppointID);


                e.ViewInfo.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromName(_newAppointmentType.Color);
            }
        }
  }
```

Here you can see my context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using WindowsFormsApplication1.Classes.LookUps;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class SourceContext : ContextBase
    {
        public SMBASchedulerEntities _sourceEntities = new SMBASchedulerEntities();
     private  SystemDa _systemDB = new SystemDa();

public   Appointment getApppointmentById(int AppointmentId)
    {
        Appointment q;
        try
        {

            if (AppointmentId == -1)// if the patient id is -1 we want to create a new record.
            {
                Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
                return appointment;

            }
            q=  _sourceEntities.Appointments
                .Where(w => w.ID == AppointmentId).SingleOrDefault();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("   etApppointmentById(int AppointmentId) failed.", ex);
        }
        return q;
    }


    public AppointmentType getAppointmentTypesById(int appointmentTypeId)
    {
        AppointmentType _appointmentTypes = new AppointmentType();
        try
        {
            _appointmentTypes = _sourceEntities.AppointmentTypes
                .Where(a => a.ID == appointmentTypeId).FirstOrDefault();
        }


        catch (Exception EX)
        {

        }
        return _appointmentTypes;
    }
```

}
But the error I am getting is

> {"Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}

Also it would randomly change the message to say currecnt connection is open is there like a RetainSameConnection = True property for entity ?

I do not understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: There are many issues in your code. I suspect you are incorrectly managing the lifetime of the context but you should start by adhering to basic coding standards for C#. Do not catch `System.Exception`, use PascalCase for method names, use `?.` and `is` to handle nullable values, do not catch exceptions unless you can handle them, keep the lifetimes of resources short, avoid reaching for `try` and `catch`, avoid deep inheritance hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Aluan Haddad From the above answer was indead correct what I had to do was make a context factory and that solved my problem

```
public  class ContextFactory  
{

   public static SourceContext ObtainContext()
   {

        SourceContext context = null;
        string key = Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString();
        LocalDataStoreSlot slot = Thread.GetNamedDataSlot(key);
        if (slot != null)
        {
            context = (SourceContext)Thread.GetData(slot);
        }
        if (context == null)
        {
            context = new SourceContext();
            if (slot == null)
            {
                slot = Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot(key);
            }
            Thread.SetData(slot, context);
        }
        return context;
    }

   }
}
```

This is then called in a different way to what I was doing above.

```
SourceContext SourceDal = ContextFactory.ObtainContext();
```

Hope this helps anyone else that comes across this type of question.